# How to add outbound rewrite rules in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, url-rewriting

I'm using a simple outbound rewrite rule to serve static resources from CDN. It works great on IIS but it isn't working in ASP.NET Core.

```
<outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
  <rule name="CDN" preCondition="CheckHTML" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match filterByTags="Img, Link, Script" pattern="(^(?!www\.|(?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/|[A-Za-z]:\\|\/\/).*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|svg|ico|gif).*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="https://cdn.com{R:1}" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    </conditions>
  </rule>
  <preConditions>
    <preCondition name="CheckHTML">
      <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
    </preCondition>
  </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Microsoft Docs has a sample but not on outbound URL (as middleware), and mentions this feature isn't available as of now with the Middleware.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2#unsupported-features
>   [image]

I have an ASP.NET Core web app hosted on Microsoft Azure. How do I enable outbound rewrite rules on it?

Has anyone worked on outbound rewrite rules in ASP.NET Core? please help!

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. ASP.NET Core is the framework, and that is the same across all hosting patterns. IIS can host ASP.NET Core apps (optionally "in process" in v2.2+ or as a reverse proxy to Kestrel), or you can use Kestrel directly (in which case HTTP.sys is your "host"). I assume you're talking about the latter scenario, in which case, no. HTTP.sys has no rewrite functionality, so you're completely dependent on the middleware which of course does not support outbound rules. If you need outbound rules, then you'll need to host in IIS (or another full web server such as Apache, Nginx, etc.)

Comment: thanks, @Chris. Is there any workaround for outbound rewrite functionality if you have ASP.NET Core Web App hosted on Azure?

Comment: update: I could not find a proper workaround to have outbound rewrite rules in web.config file. It doesn't work. I had to pre-fix the static resources with "domain".